Installed cuda with tensorflow but still my rtx 3050 isn't getting recognized by python
I installed tensorflow using https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows-native
and also installed and reinstalled cuda toolkits accordingly may be 5 to 6 times but tensorflow isn't recognizing my rtx3050
I tried to install python 3.10 then tensorflow <2.11 , cudatoolkit = 11.2 and cudnn=8.8.1
